# viewing ip camera video in desktop java application

Tags: java, video, ip-camera

I'm working on a school project where I'm going to buy an IP camera and create a Java desktop application in which user can view the video.

Please let me know what to use for viewing the video in application without opening any browser such as chrome, mozilla, etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Some critical information is missing.
How does the camera provide the video stream? When you've got the name of the format, there is a good chance some else already programmed some java player.

It seems you can access the camera via http. You could do a trick an open the page (or a html file build by you which just shows the stream without anything else) via http and display it in a html view, for example [JavaFX's Webview](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm)